# Converting a data-frame into time series in R

Tags: r, statistics, timeserieschart

I have 3 years of daily data in a column and need to write the code in R to convert the data-frame into a time series object but I am unsure of the coding.  I attach the raw data.  I was wondering whether to set the frequency to monthly or leave it daily, or whether to adapt the raw data to make it more user friendly in R.  Any advice/help would be appreciated.
Thanks
Martin.

I couldn't get the code to load up.  I then changed the frequency to just a year and 1 and it accepted the data but it is not giving the full picture.

```
This is the R code
`install.packages("readxl")
install.packages("forecast")
install.packages("tseries")

library(readxl)
library(forecast)
library(tseries)
asb <- read_excel("C://Users//BCCAMNHY//OneDrive - Birmingham City Council//HomeFiles//My Documents//DATA ANALYST TRAINING//PROJECT 4//PROJECT DOCUMENTS//ASB_311022.xlsx")

View(asb)
class(
asbtime=ts(asb$`ASB Submitted`,start = min(asb$`Date for R`,end = max(asb$`Date for R`),frequency = 12)
class(asbtime)
library(forecast)
library(tseries)
plot(asbtime)
acf(asbtime)
pacf(asbtime)
adf.test(asbtime)
gdpmodel=auto.arima(gdptime,ic="aic",trace = TRUE) ## dont understand this line of code
acf(ts(asb$residuals)) # not sure if this code should be changed to asb$asb submitted
pacf(ts(asb$residuals))# as above
myasbforecast=forecast(asbmodel,level = c(95),h=10*4) ##### Don't understand this line of code.  Want a monthly or daily forecast - think ideally monthly
mygdpforecast
plot(asbforecast)
Box.test(myasbforecast$resid, lag=5, type= "Ljung-Box")
Box.test(mygdpforecast$resid, lag=15, type= "Ljung-Box")
Box.test(myasbforecast$resid, lag=25, type= "Ljung-Box")
```

```
An extract of the raw data is:
Submitted   Count of Submitted
01/03/2019  1
02/03/2019  0
03/03/2019  0
04/03/2019  0
05/03/2019  1
06/03/2019  0
07/03/2019  1
08/03/2019  2
09/03/2019  0
10/03/2019  0
11/03/2019  27
12/03/2019  54
13/03/2019  52
14/03/2019  46
15/03/2019  44
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the names of the data columns do not match those used in the code. I think it's a coincidence but check it out anyway.
IMHO, these will be enought for conversion into ts:

```
asbtime=ts(asb$`Count of Submitted`, start=2019, frequency = 365)
plot(forecast(asbtime), xlab = "year", ylab="Submitted")
```